# Regex is not fetching the correct values from all fields

Tags: java, regex, selenium

I need to fetch the data from a PDF file and use it as a test data to test an application using Selenium Webdriver.

I stored the pdf data in a variable and fetching the required data one by one.

Now the problem I am facing here is that the below data can be multiple times in that file, only the data in bold will be changing. I need to fetch those bold values.

Airline Record Locator **JUI1244**

Airline **XXX Airlines**

Flight **HU124**

Origin **CCC CST Airport**

Destination **XXX YYY, International**

Departing **07:35 PM**

Arriving **09:20 AM / 24 Oct 2015**

Departure **Terminal Terminal C**

Arrival **Terminal Terminal 1**

I tried Substring to get the value but it is always giving me the first instance value. So, I tried to use Regex and was able to get the 'Airline Record Locator' line value using below regex

```
 Matcher m1 = Pattern.compile("(?m)(?:^Airline Record Locator )([a-zA-Z]+([0-9]+).*)").matcher(data);
while(m1.find()) {
        System.out.println(m1.group(1));
}
```

Above regex doesn't fetch data from 'Airline' line, so for that I used the below regex.

```
 Pattern.compile("(?m)(?:^Airline )([A-Z]*.*?[a-z]$)").matcher(data);
```

But both the above regex code is not fetching the values from other fields  like 'Departing', 'Arrival Terminal', 'Departing Terminal' etc.. line data.

My question

1. How to fetch the values from above fields 'Departing', 'Arrival Terminal', 'Departing Terminal' etc. ?
2. Do I need to use different regex patterns to fetch the values from different fields ? Or is there any way I can use a single regex pattern to fetch the data from all lines (Obviously the String can be different but can we have the same regex pattern ) ?

I am new to Regex and any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have u tried by splitting using split method in java which acts on a string string.split(" ");//will split by spaces.Kindly get back if you need more details

Comment: Can we mention where to stop using Split ? I tried with the below code and it is printing the whole data.

     for (String retval: data.split("Airline Record Locator ")){
          System.out.println(retval);
       }

I tried with limit as well but still it is printing the whole data.  Please let me know if I am missing something

Comment: We can't see the code you mentioned in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void test(String totalstring,String valueof){

        String arr[]=totalstring.split(valueof);

        System.out.println(arr[1].trim());

        }

//pass the line and the String for which u want the value ex : Depature
String totalstring ="Departure Terminal Terminal C";

String valueof="Departure";

test(totalstring,valueof);
```

Hope this helps you.Kindly get back if you need any further help

Comment: Thank you. It didn't gave me the exact data which I was looking for but at least gave me the data on which I can further work on to get my desired data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this solution by regex:

```
/(.*?)((Airline Record Locator\s+(.*))|(Airline\s+(.*))|(Flight\s+(.*))|(Origin\s+(.*))|(Destination\s+(.*))|(Departing\s+(.*))|(Arriving\s+(.*))|(Departure Terminal\s+(.*))|(Arrival Terminal\s+(.*)))\s*/ig
```

That substitutions will give you values like `\4`, `\6`, `\8`, ... and `\20`

[[Regex Demo]](https://regex101.com/r/qS7hJ1/1)

Comment: Hi @shA.t, Thanks for the response. I'll work more on this solution and will let you know.(I need check how can I utilize the values \4, \6 etc...

Comment: When `i` is your field number then it is `2 + 2* i` ;).